# Odoo 13 Error: Expected singleton when swapping to tree view

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

This error returns 2 records for a field that can only hold 1. It happens when I want to swap from calendar view to tree view. I assume it's because of the `compute` function, but I don't understand where's the mistake in my code. I compute field for 2 different models:

class LeaveOff:

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, tools
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, AccessError, ValidationError
from odoo.tools import date_utils


class LeaveOff(models.Model):
    _name = 'project.leaveoff'

    employ_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', required='1')

    begin_date = fields.Date('from', required='1')

    # only_oneday = fields.Selection(
    # [('Typ1', 'More than one day'), ('Typ2', 'One day')], default='Typ1')

    end_date = fields.Date('to')

    day_hours = fields.Float('Hours per day', default='8.00', required='1')

    requested_hours = fields.Float(
        'LeaveOff Hours', compute='_compute_requested_hours')

    def _compute_requested_hours(self):

        for record in self:
            if record.employ_id.id:
                start = self.begin_date
                end = self.end_date
                delta = end - start
                self.requested_hours = self.day_hours * (delta.days + 1)
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Action for leaveoffs -->
<odoo>
  <record id="action_for_leaveoff" model="ir.actions.act_window">
          <field name="name">LeaveOff</field>
          <field name="res_model">project.leaveoff</field>
          <field name="view_mode">calendar,tree,form</field>
          <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
              Here, you can enter LeaveOff Times from your employees!
            </p>
          </field>
  </record>
  <!-- form view -->
  <record id="project_leaveoff_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
          <field name="name">view.project.leaveoff.form</field>
          <field name="model">project.leaveoff</field>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
              <form string="Manage your Employee's TimeOff">
                  <sheet>
                    <group>
                       <field name="employ_id" string="Employee-Name" />
                       <!-- <field name="only_oneday"/> -->
                       <field name="begin_date"/>
                       <field name="end_date"/>
                       <field name="day_hours"/>
                    </group>
                    <div>
                    <group>
                       <field name="requested_hours" readonly="1"/>
                    </group>
                    </div>
                  </sheet>
              </form>
          </field>
  </record>
  <record id="project_leaveoff_calendar_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.project.leaveoff.calendar</field>
    <field name="model">project.leaveoff</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <calendar string="LeaveOff Calendar" date_start="begin_date" date_stop="end_date" color="employ_id">
            <field name="employ_id"  string="Employee"/>
            <field name="day_hours" string="Hours per day"/>
        </calendar>
    </field>
  </record>
  <!-- create action -->
  <!-- tree view -->
  <record id="project_leaveoff_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
          <field name="name">view.project.leaveoff.tree</field>
          <field name="model">project.leaveoff</field>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="LeaveOff-Time">
              <field name="employ_id" string="Employee-Name"/>
              <field name="begin_date"/>
              <field name="end_date"/>
              <field name="day_hours"/>
              <field name="requested_hours"/>
            </tree>
          </field>
  </record>
  <menuitem  id="menu_main_leaveoff" name="LeaveOff" parent="project.menu_main_pm" action="action_for_leaveoff"/>
</odoo>
```

And the Odoo error:

> Error: Odoo Server Error
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 745, in get
> value = self._data[field][record._ids[0]] KeyError: 51
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1004, in **get**
> value = env.cache.get(record, self)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 751, in get
> raise CacheMiss(record, field) odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: ('project.leaveoff(51,).requested_hours', None)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5101, in
> ensure_one
> _id, = self._ids ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 624, in
> _handle_exception
> return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 310, in
> _handle_exception
> raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in
> reraise
> raise value   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 669, in dispatch
> result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 350, in
> _call_function
> return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in
> wrapper
> return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 339, in
> checked_call
> result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 915, in **call**
> return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 515, in
> response_wrap
> response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py",
> line 1285, in search_read
> return self.do_search_read(model, fields, offset, limit, domain, sort)   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py",
> line 1304, in do_search_read
> return Model.web_search_read(domain, fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=sort)   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/models/models.py",
> line 39, in web_search_read
> records = self.search_read(domain, fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order)   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4951, in
> search_read
> result = records.read(fields)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 2965, in read
> vals[name] = convert(record[name], record, use_name_get)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5731, in
> **getitem**
> return self._fields[key].**get**(self, type(self))   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1028, in **get**
> self.compute_value(recs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1113, in
> compute_value
> records._compute_field_value(self)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4003, in
> _compute_field_value
> getattr(self, field.compute)()   File "/opt/Odoo/Custom_Addon/project_addon/models/leaveoff.py", line 31, in
> _compute_requested_hours
> start = self.begin_date   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 988, in **get**
> record.ensure_one()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5104, in
> ensure_one
> raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self) ValueError: Expected singleton: project.leaveoff(51, 52)

Could someone help me, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem has it in your `compute` method.

```
def _compute_requested_hours(self):
    for record in self:
        # Change here (Assigned before if the below condition not full-fill it still set the 0.0 value)
        record.requested_hours = 0.0
        if record.employ_id.id:
            start = record.begin_date
            end = record.end_date
            delta = end - start
            # Change here
            record.requested_hours = record.day_hours * (delta.days + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you @Dipen Shah. 
I know that in the loop the old value is saved that's why i have to put the value back to zero. 
 Unfortunately I still get the singleton error.

Comment: improved code, I forgot to change loop for all inside line usage.